# Write /etc/hosts via ansible using variables inside magical variables

Tags: ansible, cluster-computing

I'm trying to write file /etc/hosts via ansible for cluster purposes. I want to use group_vars variable inside of magical variables. Here is working  example, where I use **ansibe_default_ipv4** without group_vars variable:

```
    - name: Add hosts to /etc/hosts
      lineinfile:
      args:
         dest: "/etc/hosts"
         regexp: "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}"
         line: "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }} {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_fqdn'] }}   {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_fqdn'].split('.')[0] }}"
      with_items: "{{ play_hosts }}"
      tags: ha-cluster
```

But I want to use something like **ansible_{{ cluster_interface }}** instead of **ansible_default_ipv4**, where **cluster_interface** is the variable in group_vars, like *eth0* or *eth1*. To make role more flexible with using certain interfaces for different clusters.

Here is not working example:

```
    - name: Add hosts to /etc/hosts
      lineinfile:
      args:
         dest: "/etc/hosts"
         regexp: "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}"
         line: "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_{{ cluster_ineterface }}']['ipv4']['address'] }} {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_fqdn'] }}   {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_fqdn'].split('.')[0] }}"
      with_items: "{{ play_hosts }}"
      tags: ha-cluster
```

The error:

```
fatal: [node1.linux.cluster.test]: FAILED! => {
"failed": true, 
"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. 
The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_{{ cluster_interface }}'\n
\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/name/.ansible/roles/ha-cluster/tasks/main.yml': 
line 36, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n
\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Add hosts to /etc/hosts\n  ^ here\n"
}
```

Ansible Version: 2.2.1.0-2

Host: Debian 9.4

Is it even possible to use group_vars inside of magical vars?
Thank you!